# quelle est une expression française pour le lettrage mathématique tel que ℝℕℤ?

Tags: technologie

Veuillez consulter les lettres ci-dessous

```
ℝℕℤ
```

Je vais expliquer le contexte de mes questions afin que la qualité soit élevée.

Il existe un langage de programmation pour la composition appelé **MathJax**.

**MathJax** contient des centaines de commandes et chaque commande est une séquence d'une phrase en anglais.

Par exemple, lorsque nous rendons **MathJax**, l'entrée est `\mathbb{Z}` et la sortie est `ℤ`.

`\mathbb` est une sous-séquence de l'expression anglaise 《mathématics blackboard》

Je pensais qu'un projet amusant serait de modifier MathJax.

Dans ma variante rétrocompatible de MathJax, il est bon que les gens tapent les choses à l'ancienne. Si les gens tapent les choses de la nouvelle manière, ce sera bien aussi. Le résultat serait que les gens pourraient utiliser des sous-séquences de phrases en anglais ou en allemand pour certaines des commandes.

- `\mbbb{Z}`
- `\mathbb{Z}`
- `\mathematicsblackboardbold{Z}`
- `\mathématiquesbrutesbravoure{Z}`
- `\mgbrav{Z}`

toutes les sous-séquences d'une phrase seraient autorisées à condition que nous n'ayons pas deux commandes ou plus dans l'espace actuel qui sépare la même sous-séquence.

¿Quelle est l'expression allemande pour 《tableau noir double barré gras》?

Comment: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gras_de_tableau_noir) l'appelle 
*le gras de/du tableau noir* ou *lettres ajourées* ou *lettres double barre* ou *blackboard gras*. Je ne poste pas de réponse parce que je ne sais pas laquelle de ces expressions est la plus courante.

Comment: Pour le trouver, j'ai cherché "blackboard bold" dans le wikipedia anglais, et puis cliqué sur "français".

Comment: Mais nous sommes habitués à utiliser MathJax en anglais. J'écris pas mal de maths en Latex, et j'ai l'anglais au bout des doigts pour ces commandes. Il faudrait faire un effort pour écrire "mathématiquesbrutesbravoure{Z}".

Comment: En langue courante, le terme lettre ajourée ou lettre double barre me semble le plus compréhensible. Je ne connaissait pas le terme "gras de tableau noir". Mais peut être "black board bold" ne fait-il pas partie de la langue courante non plus en anglais...

Comment: @XouDo: Parmi les mathématiciens, "blackboard bold" est couramment utilisé, peut-être à cause de LaTeX.

Comment: [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lettrage) : Lettrage, subst. masc.,,Action de marquer avec des lettres`` (Lar. Lang. fr.).  — «ℝℕℤ » n'est pas une action, mais peut être le _résultat_ d'une action. « Lettrage » ne signifie pas « style de lettre » ; «ℝℕℤ » n'est pas un style de lettre mais  _sont des lettres d'un style donnée_ (quel que soit le nom du style particulier).